# Biggest ellipse included in a convex polygon

Tags: geometry, convex-optimization, conic-sections, polygons, polyhedra

Considering a **N** edges convex 2D polygon called **P**.
Let's name its vertices $\{p_1, p_2, ..., p_N\}$ described in a counter-clockwise order, with $p_i = (x_i, y_i)$

What would be, and how would one compute(preferably without optimization algorithm) the ellipse of biggest area **E** included in this polygon?

Comment: I'm not even sure how to do it for circles.

Comment: I don't think you are going to get a neat, computable on the paper type of algorithm for this problem. Most probably, some sort of optimization is indeed needed. After a brisk googling, this paper came up http://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.3193.pdf . It discusses about same problem in the context of circles.

Comment: The solution to the dual problem (smallest enclosing ellipse) is given here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22562/how-to-find-the-smallest-area-ellipse-circumscribing-a-convex-polygon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by converting the given polygon from a set of vertices to a set of linear inequalities. Then one can use convex optimization. From chapter 8 of Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/):

---

[image]

Comment: Here is some [CVX code](http://web.cvxr.com/cvx/examples/cvxbook/Ch08_geometric_probs/html/max_vol_ellip_in_polyhedra.html).