# a set of linear constraints defines a smaller and smaller set, to what extent?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

Let's say I have a set of linear constraints over $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ in the form of $Ax \le b$.

Is there a way to know the ``volume'' of the feasible set (in the sense that every two points in the feasible set are within $\epsilon$ distance)?

Is there some conditions under which the feasible set is just a unique point?

EDIT: I have looked around, and the potential to find the volume of a polyhedron looks quite grim. I am wondering if there are a few well-known results that give some reasonable bound on the volume of the polyhedron as a function of some characteristics of the polyhedron. Again, not extremely hopeful...

Comment: Are you looking for the volume or diameter?  The diameter of a set is the maximum distance between two points.

Comment: This may be of interest https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/509486/biggest-ellipse-included-in-a-convex-polygon

Comment: @JosephCamacho I was hoping to find some sort of a diameter for the polyhedron, which through then I could bound the polyhedron with a sphere - and the volume of a sphere is easy to compute given its diameter.

Comment: @KBS unfortunately not quite what I am looking for, I think, because in that case the ellipsoid is inside the polyhedron (isn't it?)

Comment: @kloop but it is what you want. If the ellipse has zero radius or very small you get pretty much what you are aiming for.